# use "#" operator to calculate the length of a table in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a question when I use `#` to calculte the length of a table. For Example:

```
local t = {"a", "b"}
local t1 = {"a", nil}
print(#t)       -- 2
print(#t1)      -- 1
```

---

```
local t = {"a", "b"}
local t1 = {nil, "a"}
print(#t)       -- 2
print(#t1)      -- 2
```

can someone tell me why it is?

Answer (score 3):

Unless `__len` metamethod is defined, `#` operator can only be operated on a table that is a sequence.

A sequence is, a table that, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to `{1..n}` for some non-negative integer `n`.

In your example:

---

```
local t = {"a", "b"}
```

`t` is a sequence that has a length of `2`.

---

```
local t1 = {"a", nil}
```

is equivalent to `local t1 = {"a"}`, so `t1` is a sequence that has a length of `1`.

---

```
local t1 = {nil, "a"}
```

`t1` is not a sequence, so `#t1` is not defined.

Comment: local t1 = {nil, "a"}   t1 is not a sequence, dose it mean that #t1 returns a wrong length.

Comment: @user1723404 There is no agreed on "right" length for a table that is not a sequence. In practice, for a non-sequence, Lua might return different results for tables that have the same entries. For example, if you test `local t1 = {nil, "a"}; print(#t1)` you will probably get `2`. But if you test `local t1={}; t[1]=nil; t[2]="a"; print(#t1)` you will probably get `0`.

Comment: @user1723404 `#t1` is not defined, means there's no *correct* value of it. In particular, it's possible that you get different value in different Lua implementations.